# Leaflet WebMap not loading properly

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I'm having an issue when embedding a Leaflet webmap into a webpage. It is being placed in the webpage exactly where I want it to be place, but the map itself is not appearing properly. The map loads like this.

[image]

And this is the code that I have written.

```
//variable to initialize the map
var map = L.map('map',{
    center: [51.00, 0.00],
    zoom: 7
});

//load the OpenStreetMap/Leaflet basemap tile layer
var OpenStreetMap_HOT = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

//initialize customized marker icon
var myIcon = L.icon({iconUrl: 'img/stadium.png'}); //BE SURE TO CREDIT ICON SOURCE: Stadium 
icon made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/stadium" title="stadium 
icons">Stadium icons created by Freepik - Flaticon</a>

//initialize Marker Cluster Leaflet plugin
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    showCoverageOnHover: false
});

//initialize GeoJSON.js data layer
var geoJsonLayer = new L.geoJson(EFL_Stadiums_EPSG4326, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup("<h2 class='infoheader'>English Football League Clubs</h2><b><h3 
class='clubinfoheader'>" + feature.properties.Club +"</h3><b><p class='stadiuminfoheader'>" + 
feature.properties.Stadium +"</p><b><p class='leagueinfoheader'>" + feature.properties.League 
+"</p></b>" + "<p class='webinfoheader'>" + "<a href='" + feature.properties.Website + "' 
target=blank>Link to Website</a></p>");
        layer.setIcon(myIcon);},
        pointTolayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng);}
});

markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

map.addLayer(markers);

map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());

L.control.betterscale().addTo(map);

L.control.ruler().addTo(map);

//initialize ZoomBox Leaflet plugin
var options = {modal: true,title: "Box area zoom"};

var control = L.control.zoomBox(options);

map.addControl(control);
```

Are there any solutions to get this map to load correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your map ends up with a centering and scale which is not the one that you expect.

Taking your sample code and only using its most generic part as we don't have your Feature data:

```
    var map = L.map('map',{
    center: [51.00, 0.00],
    zoom: 7
});

//load the OpenStreetMap/Leaflet basemap tile layer
var OpenStreetMap_HOT = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

L.control.betterscale().addTo(map);

L.control.ruler().addTo(map);

//initialize ZoomBox Leaflet plugin
var options = {modal: true,title: "Box area zoom"};

var control = L.control.zoomBox(options);

map.addControl(control);
```

The result seems appropriate : centered on (51,0) and zoom level 7

[image]

This suggest the issue relates to the `map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());` which is applied after the initial map centering